# Prefix filtering in php

Tags: php

How can I write a php program to find all arrays which share at least a single element in their prefixes. Let the prefixes are one fourth of the total elements in each array. Can anyone help me to code for that? I am a fresher in php. I need this to do a project regarding near duplicate detection.

Comment: This might be the solution you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878460/optimizing-near-duplicate-value-search

Comment: x={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}, y={B,X,Y,Z}, z={F,G,H,A,B}, q={B,R} Then in the result, we should get the pairs {(x,y),(y,q),(x,q)}

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's built in array function [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
if(array_intersect($firstArray, $secondArray) == null)
{
    //do not have any element common
}
else 
{
    //have at least one element common
}
```

you can create function of this code and pass all array's pairs to get result.